# C# How invoke this Javascript In c#?

Tags: c#, javascript

I want to invoke this javascript.

```
 //<BUTTON id="TestID" class="My_Test button small" type="submit"><SPAN class="account">By</SPAN></BUTTON>
```

How can I send this command without use the mouse an click the button on the form??

There is alott of invoke examples but I cant figure out how to make this click event trigger by code...

Comment: what javascript do you want to invoke? i see no javascript. And what does this have to do with C#?

Comment: There are quite a few problems with your question, mainly because that's HTML, not JavaScript, and I really don't see what C# has to do with this at all.

Comment: where is the javascript? and you can't invoke javascript from c# since your c# code will run on the server and you javascript code on the client. What you can do is create some other javascript code that runs your javascript code when some criteria is met.

Comment: Re edit: how do you invoke a JavaScript comment?

Comment: Sorry first time I ask a question. Now the code should be there. Im Using the webbrowser in a windows form,and want to send the click event by code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to automatically click that button, you would want to take advantage of the browser's JavaScript engine, rather than doing anything with C#.

For instance, you can add a `<script>` tag at the top of that with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("TestID").click();
</script>
```

Comment: But I had to use: HtmlElement  
Insted of <script type="">
 try 
{ //Link the ID from the web form to the Button var theButton = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("place_bid_20112"); // Now do the actual click. theButton.InvokeMember("click"); } catch { }

Answer (score 0):

In your page in the ASPX you could create a block like this:

```
<script type="javascript">
    document.getElementById(<%= TestID.ClientID>).click();
</script>
```

however my code assumes that you meant to write: (or something to this effect)

```
<asp:Button id="TestID" runat="server" class="My_Test button small" type="submit">
  <SPAN class="account">By</SPAN>
</asp:Button>
```

But that would run as soon as you loaded the page. But it's still a viable option. Most likely you want to have it click the button based on some other action, yes?

Have you considered using a javascript framework to make some of this easier (and make cross-platform support a lot easier)? Are you already using a javascript framework of some sort? If so, which one?

Comment: Sorry first time I ask a question. Now the code should be there. Im Using the webbrowser in a windows form,and want to send the click event by code when I want to bycode.

Comment: This works: HtmlElement theButton; try { //Link the ID from the web form to the Button var theButton = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Test_Id"); // Now do the actual click. theButton.InvokeMember("click"); } catch { }

Comment: You must be relying on the .NET javascript framework, in which case you could use $get("test id") to get the ID if I'm not mistaken. But yes, that's more or less what I was implying.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if that code sample is using [vapor.js](http://vaporjs.com/). The good news is that C# automatically causes all of vapor.js to be executed between every machine instruction while your program is running.  Thus, your code is **already** invoking the JavaScript. The bug must be elsewhere.

Comment: very funny but I don't think he'll get the joke.

Comment: It's worth a down-vote or two. Besides, it's not technically inaccurate - as far as I can tell, vapor.js is being evaluated continually by all the computing devices in my house (including my dishwasher).

Comment: I'm pretty sure he just changed the game here ... running in a c# winforms app ... hrm

Answer (score 0):

You can't. JavaScript requires the use of its scripting host (embedded in the web browser), and cannot be triggered by anything but other JavaScript or an event of the scripting host that calls JavaScript code. Now, you can run the handlers from anywhere; they're just JS functions. So, you could set up the same function to execute for document.OnLoad and when the document shows up it would act like that button had been clicked.

To test JavaScript in an automated fashion, you usually need something that will script UI actions. In FireFox, iMacros is a simple and free tool that can perform scripted actions with a decent amount of conditional logic. Selenium RC is a Windows scripting host that has far more flexibility and interop with programming languages (so you can integrate it into automated acceptance testing frameworks like Fitnesse).

Comment: What about server-side JavaScript interpreters like Rhino or V8?

Comment: @drachenstern your psychic powers are way sharper than mine :-)